# Strong measurability - simpler solution?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, bochner-spaces

I have recently started to study vector valued integration. I wish to prove the following claim:

> Assume that $u(t)\in L^2(I;L^2(\Omega))$ where $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an (open) bounded interval and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a lipschitz function. Then $f(u(t)):I\rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ is strongly measurable.

Much to my surprise, I couldn't come up with a simple proof than this one:

> As $u(t):I\rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ is strongly measurable, the function $u(t,x):I\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable (I had already proven this proposition). As $f$ is cts., $f(u(t,x)):I\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. It's easy to show that $f(u(t,x))\in L^2(I\times\Omega)$. Hence, the function $f(u(t)):I\rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ is strongly measurable (again, I had already proven this).

However, I feel like I'm using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.
If anyone could show me an elementary argument (after which I'll probably feel ashamed), I'll be grateful. Thank you

Comment: Hi, it's been a while since you put up this post, but can I ask you a question regarding your post? In your post, it says, "As $u(t)$ is strongly measurable, the function $u(t,x)$ is measurable. Can you elaborate on it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Lipschitz property of $f $, show that the (nonlinear) map
$$
T_f : L^2 (\Omega) \to L^2 (\Omega), u \mapsto f \circ u
$$
is continuous. For well-definedness, we use that $\Omega $ is bounded (otherwise,  assume  $f (0)=0$).

Now, if $G : X \to B $ is strongly measurable and if $F : B \to C $ is continuous (with Banach spaces $B,C $ and a measure space $X $), it is not hard to show (do it!) that $F \circ G $ is strongly measurable. Depending on your exact definition of strong measurability, you will also need to assume that $X $ is sigma finite.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the type of argument I was looking for. $F\circ G_n$ go (strongly) to $F\circ G$ a.e. where $G_n$ are simple functions that converge strongly to $G$ a.e.  Hence $F\circ G$ is strongly measurable. How do I know that $F\circ G_n$ are strongly measurable, though? If $F$ were linear, it would be obvious but $F$ needn't be linear.

Comment: @user1321324: If $G_n$ is simple, then so is $F \circ G_n$ (and the "steps" are still measurable sets).

Comment: Oh, my bad... Thank you a lot!